# Dynamic Object Reference data.d.results.[fieldobjectname].[fieldname] in JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint, dynamic, reference, notation, square-bracket

**BACKGROUND**:
Using SharePoint 2013, calling a REST Ajax call in javascript. When successful, this returns results in a data set, which I put in a variable called data.

My OData syntax uses $expand on a SharePoint Person `{the datatype}` field, such that I can return the person's name, as well as their ID.

So, in the `call.done function(data, status, jqXHR)` , if the field being "expanded" is called "Employee", then the data results can be accessed by using a for loop and step through the returned data using:

```
 for (var i=0; i<data.d.results.length i++) {
  var id  data.d.results[i].Employee.Id
  var emp data.d.results[i].Employee.Title
  }
```

**DESIRE**:
I'd like to dynamically pass a field name, such that I can do something like:

```
var emp = data.d.results[i].[pField].Title
```

**PROBLEM**:
This Bracket Notation, nor any variation, works.

**QUESTION**:
Is it possible to dynamically reference this object name, returned by the `$Expand [object]`, and if so, what is the proper format?

Thanks,

Steve Clark - Easy Bins Dumpster Rentals | http://www.easy-bins.com